# combine or add 2 lists in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists of tuples of the format `List<Tuple<string, int, long>>` that I need to merge.  I want the second list to go after the first one, so the items aren't all mixed up.  I figured this should be fairly easy but found nothing helpful in my searching.

Comment: Did you see `AddRange()`?

Comment: You can also use LINQ's `Concat` method (and `ToList` if necessary).

Comment: So you didn't read any documentation on `List<T>`, is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`AddRange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) to add the second list to the first.

```
var firstList.AddRange(secondList);
```

This will add the items from the second list to the end of the first list.

Answer (score 6):

Having

```
List<Tuple<string, int, long>> fistList = //your first list
List<Tuple<string, int, long>> secondList = //your second list
```

**This makes a new list:**

```
var result = fistList.Concat(secondList).ToList()
```

**This add second list to the first one**

```
fistList.AddRange(secondList);
```